# How to create a table inside a flask application hosted on heroku?

Tags: python, database, flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

I have created a table with SQLAlchemy inside a flask application in this application I implemented a python code to query data in an SQLite database.

```
def create_connection(db_file):

    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn


def select_itens(conn, column):

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(" SELECT %s FROM table WHERE id=1" %(column))

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    return rows

def data_select(column):

    # create a database connection
    conn = create_connection(database)
    with conn:
        data = select_itens(conn, column)
    
    return data
```

On my local host the project works perfectly. However, when I deployed it to heroku I caught some errors.

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/app/main.py", line 124, in services
data_select("user")
File "/app/database.py", line 76, in data_select
select_itens(conn, column)
File "/app/database.py", line 51, in select_itens
cur.execute(" SELECT %s FROM teste WHERE id=1" %(column))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: teste
```

I migrated my database following this post [Setting up flask app in heroku with a database](https://gist.github.com/mayukh18/2223bc8fc152631205abd7cbf1efdd41/). But from the error it says that the table does not exist, so possibly I am forgetting something.

This test table was created via the command prompt as follows:

```
->> from main import db

->> db.create_all()
```

main.py

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
#Create db model

class Teste(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    user = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    #Create function to return a srting when we add something

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Information %r>' % self.id
```

This is the first application I have deployed with a database, so I am still learning. Do I need to create the *test* table inside heroku or does the migration I did solve this problem?

Comment: Probably the path to the database is wrong or ambiguous. Have you entered a fully-qualified path (instead of relative path)? It's very possible that the ORM created a new but blank DB file, and thus is not pointing to the right file.

Comment: You are correct, I solved the problem by creating a table in the specified path.